# SOLANA sendAndConfirmTransaction and sendTransaction ERROR ( unexpected type, use Uint8Array)

Tags: solana, uint8array

It has been a real big issue finding solution to the error on Solana Transaction API
I have sent several messages to the tech discord group and the Telegram group and still did not find any of the Solana tech developers who can solve the issue. I have read and applied all the suggestions written on their example codes, and many of their documents on their website, and all these are working or solving the issue. I also noticed I am not the only one going through the issue and haven't gotten a satisfying solution to the error.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.js"></script>

<!-- Production (minified) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
```

This is the code:

```
  await window.solana.connect();

    const provider = window.solana;
    console.log("Public key of the emitter: ",provider.publicKey.toString());

     var connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(
      solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
    );

    var recieverWallet = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("FjXye8TxWjxCvA9wmL8vhfzmQXfxjp5LYhBBZCHY4h5B");
 
     transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
     transaction.add(
      solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: provider.publicKey,
        toPubkey: recieverWallet,
        lamports: (solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 5)
      }),
    );
 
 const signature = await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection,transaction,[provider]);
```

And the error is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgLRu.png)

TypeError: unexpected type, use Uint8Array
at checkArrayTypes (nacl-fast.js:2165:13)

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that you're using the `provider` from a specific wallet to "sign" for a transaction incorrectly.

The `sendAndConfirmTransaction` method expects a `signer` where you have a `provider`. That's the current error you are getting.

With Phantom, you have to use the provider to send the transaction like this:

`await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);`

If you use the [wallet-adapter](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter), you can reference the same function across all wallets as seen in the [cookbook examples](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html).